Using AZ CLI in PowerShell to move all resources in an Azure Resource Group
I am looking to make an Azure DevOps Pipeline to move resources at the resource group level, to another subscription with an empty resource group. However, I'm running into an issue with Move-AzResource where it can't move all resources since some resources like storage accounts and VMs have a dependency on other resources. I know that the easy way to this is to just use the Azure Portal, but I was wondering if there was a way to programmable move resources instead. Any advice would help!
PowerShell Script:
# Connect to your Azure account
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX' -Subscription 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'

# Define resource group names
$sourceRG = "move-this"
$targetRG = "move-to-this"

# Specify the target subscription ID
$destinationSubscription = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" # Replace with your actual target subscription ID

# Get resources from the source resource group
$resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $sourceRG

# Move each resource to the target resource group
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    Move-AzResource -DestinationResourceGroupName $targetRG -DestinationSubscriptionId $destinationSubscription -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -Force
}


Error:
Line |
   9 |      Move-AzResource -DestinationResourceGroupName $targetRG -Destinat …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | ResourceMoveValidationFailed : The resource batch move request has '1' validation errors. Diagnostic information: timestamp '20240511T202422Z', tracking   
     | Id '791c0f0a-aa19-4929-86b0-fab99adb6ec9', request correlation Id '4502f145-7358-4076-b6ac-33987628efcf'. CorrelationId:
     | 6693eb66-f052-48da-bbb1-ab6676610a26


Tried to use Move-AzResource to move all of the resources in a resource group to a different resource group in another subscription. However, I'm getting validation errors due to the nature of the resources in that resource group.

Hi @DevinYorkDJ, Have you got a chance to check suggestion in my answer to check whether the resource has any dependent resources, and whether they're located in the same resource group? Hope the information may point to the right direction to help resolve your issue. Thx.

Hi there @AlvinZhao-MSFT, I have looked into it and am working on fine tuning my script. So far I have been able to use a DevOps pipeline to move multiple storage accounts across two different subscriptions. My next step is to move a Arc Server but I need the appropriate permissions to do so. I will post my results when I have verified that they work.

Thanks for taking time to share the update. Look forward to your good news. Cheers.

Hi @DevinYorkDJ, Good day to you. May I know the latest status of the issue and if possible, would you share your working results in the answer? Thx for the efforts to help other community members who may encounter similar issues.

Hi there @AlvinZhao-MSFT. Due to complications, I haven't been able to test this on an Arc Server, but it has worked with storage accounts and VMs.

Thanks a lot for your time and efforts to share the option to move each individual resource and detailed solution!.

I found that just moving each individual resource rather than the entire resource group was the answer. Using this script, I can list the resources I want to move in a parameter and move each resource individually through a for loop.
move.ps1:
$locationId                 = $env:locationID
$destinationId              = $env:destinationID
$destinationRg              = $env:destinationRG
$resourceList               = $env:resourceList -replace '\s', '' # Remove any whitespace

Write-Host "locationId: $locationId"
Write-Host "destinationId: $destinationId"

# Define an array of server names
$resources                  = $resourceList -split ','

# Specify the target resource group and destination subscription
$locationSubscription       = $locationId
$destinationSubscription    = $destinationId
$targetRG                   = $destinationRg

Set-AzContext -Subscription $locationSubscription
# Loop through each server name and move the resource
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    $Resource               = Get-AzResource -ResourceName $resource
    if ($Resource -ne $null) {
        # Attempt to move the resource
        try {
            Move-AzResource -DestinationResourceGroupName $targetRG -ResourceId $Resource.ResourceId -DestinationSubscriptionId $destinationSubscription -Force
            Write-Host "Moved $($Resource.Name) to $targetRG in subscription $destinationSubscription" -ForegroundColor Green
        } catch {
            # Handle the error
            Write-Host "Error moving $resource $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "Resource $resource not found in $locationSubscription!" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

move-reosurces.yml:
trigger:
- main

parameters:
- name: locationID
  type: string
  displayName: 'Where is the resource located?'
  default: '<origin-subscription-id>'

- name: destinationID
  type: string
  displayName: 'Where is the resource going?'
  default: '<destination-subscription-id>'

- name: destinationRG
  type: string
  displayName: 'Where are we putting the resource?'
  default: '<destination-resource-group>'

- name: resourcesToMove
  type: string
  displayName: "What resources are we moving?"
  default: '(Separate the resources with a comma! Ex: resource1, resource2, resource3)'

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    displayName: 'Move Resources'
    azureSubscription: '<service-principal-goes-here>'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/script/move.ps1'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
  env:
    locationID: ${{parameters.locationID}}
    destinationID: ${{parameters.destinationID}}
    destinationRG: ${{parameters.destinationRG}}
    resourceList: ${{parameters.resourcesToMove}}

This script will do the job.

I tested to use the same script as yours to move a simple Microsoft.Storage (without any dependent resources) across resource groups in different subscriptions and it succeeded. So what seemed to block you at the moment was how to know and move the dependent resources.
According to the document,

For a move across subscriptions, the resource and its dependent resources must be located in the same resource group and they must be moved together. For example, a VM with managed disks would require the VM and the managed disks to be moved together, along with other dependent resources.
If you're moving a resource to a new subscription, check to see whether the resource has any dependent resources, and whether they're located in the same resource group. If the resources aren't in the same resource group, check to see whether the resources can be combined into the same resource group. If so, bring all these resources into the same resource group by using a move operation across resource groups.
For more information, see Scenario for move across subscriptions

By the way, you may also test with the script/command to validate move scenario via Azure PowerShell to see why the validation didn't pass.
